# Copying data from one file to another file very slow in android?

Tags: java, android

I am copying data from one file to another file.
It takes more time. What's the reason?
My code is here

```
    public void copyData( InputStream in, OutputStream out ) throws IOException
    {
        try
        {
            in = new CipherInputStream( in, dcipher );
            int numRead = 0;
            byte[] buf = new byte[512];
            while ( ( numRead = in.read( buf ) ) >= 0 )
            {
                out.write( buf, 0, numRead );
            }
            out.close();
            in.close();
        }
        catch ( java.io.IOException e )
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try this `byte[] buf = new byte[1024];`

Comment: What do you mean by more time ? In comparison to what it takes more time. How much data are you trying to copy ? Where are your new and old files located ? Also the buffer size is 512 bytes, is there a reason to do so ?

Comment: My file size is 11.8 (MB). My new and old file is stored in the sdcard.

Comment: Buffer is too small, increase to 4kb or 8kb

Comment: 512 bytes buffer is **WAY** too small.

Comment: I am using operation as Encrypt/Decrypt a file. So that's the reason i am using the buffer size is 512 bytes.

Comment: If your encryption method only supports up to 512 bytes, you're doing it wrong. Start by fixing that and increase the buffer close to 1 MB.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the code, what I did is increased the buffer size and flushing the data as soon as it touches 1 MB, so that you don't encounter Out of memory error.

Reason is mainly due to small buffer size which takes time in writing small bytes of information. Better to put a large chunk at a time.

You can modify these values according to your needs.

```
public void copyData( InputStream in, OutputStream out ) throws IOException
{
    try
    {
        int numRead = 0;
        byte[] buf = new byte[102400];
        long total = 0;
        while ( ( numRead = in.read( buf ) ) >= 0 )
        {
            total += numRead;
            out.write( buf, 0, numRead );

            //flush after 1MB, so as heap memory doesn't fall short
            if (total > 1024 * 1024) 
             { 
                total = 0;
                out.flush();
             }
        }
        out.close();
        in.close();
    }
    catch ( java.io.IOException e )
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need all this. Flushing won't make it faster: slower, if anything. There is no risk of `OutOfMemoryException` with this code, unless it is writing to a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, which would be stupid, and contrary to the terms of the question.

Answer (score 0):

> I am copying data from one file to another file.

No you aren't. You are decrypting an input stream and writing the plaintext to an output stream.

> It takes more time.

More time than what?

> What's the reason?

Basically your tiny buffer size. Raise it to at least 8192 bytes: more if there continues to be a benefit.

```
int numRead = 0;
```

You don't need to initialize this variable.

```
byte[] buf = new byte[512];
```

See above. Change to at least 8192.

```
while ( ( numRead = in.read( buf ) ) >= 0 )
```

`read(byte[])` can only return zero if `buf.length` is zero, which is a programming error you don't want to loop forever on. Change the condition to `> 0`.

```
    catch ( java.io.IOException e )
    {
    }
```

*Never* ignore an exception.

> I am using operation as Encrypt/Decrypt a file. So that's the reason i am using the buffer size is 512 bytes.

No it isn't. There's nothing about encryption or decryption that requires a 512-byte buffer.

Answer (score -1):

2 Reasons

1. Buffer is too small, make it 4kb or 8kb, keep increasing until your phone crash's, then move 1 step back
2. Reading and Writing need to be on 2 different threads. As reads complete, put it on a q, and as write completes read it from the q. Dont forget to synchronize the q object.

When writing such code, you need to use CPU and Memory to its highest extent. On thread and a while loop is so College C'ish.. :)

Comment: Sorry for disturbing. Can you give me any sample part of code. Thanks.

Comment: Reading and writing do *not* need to be on different threads.